# Visual Studio Team Explorer only checkin some files

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs, visual-studio-2015, team-explorer

We're upgrading from Visual Studio 2010 to 2015. When I use Team Explorer to checkin files, on VS 2010, I could select a directory and it showed all the checked out files in that directory ***with a checkbox so I could unselect certain files I don't want to checkin***. But the checkboxes seem to be gone in 2015, so I have to checkin everything in the directory. Is there a workaround to bring back the checkbox?

(Note I am not asking for a .gitignore to *never* check in certain files. I do want to check in the files, just not yet. Right now I want to checkin only some of them).

Answer (score 0):

Right click the file in the Pending Changes view and choose "Exclude".

Comment: Does that work with git too? I have 2 files checked out on Git (and it shows that on the regular checkin window) but when I go to "Pending Changes" it gives me a warning about "TFS is not your source control" (which is correct, i'm using git) but then doesn't show me any files on that "Pending Changes" window, so I can't include/exclude. Any thing I need to do?

Answer (score 0):

The feature of "*Check Box*" is gone in VS2015. For now, there are only **Included Changes** and **Excluded Changes**.

According to your description, you just need to click and select those files(*use ctrl or shift to multiple select*) and right click "Exclude"

[image]

After the operation, **those files will add in Exclude list**. You will not check in them. Once you want to check in them again, you just need to included them back to include list.

[image]

Comment: Does that work with git too?  I have 2 files checked out on Git (and it shows that on the regular checkin window) but when I go to "Pending Changes" it gives me a warning about "TFS is not your source control" (which is correct, i'm using git) but then doesn't show me any files on that "Pending Changes" window, so I can't include/exclude. Any thing I need to do?

Comment: This also work with Git. Make sure you are working with a GIT team project. And the code is in the  local Git repositories. In Git project, it's not "pending changes" , it's "changes"